# Workaround for a lack of multiple inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I am currently working on a videogame (assignment), and the problem I have is the following:

The player can move vertically and horizontally, but some other objects can only move vertically OR horizontally. I would love to have an abstract class "HorizontalMovingObject" and "VerticalMovingObject", and have an abstract class "MovingObject" which extends both these classes. I was wondering if there happens to be a workaround for this?

I currently have these abstract classes, but find myself constantly copying code from the unidimensional moving classes to the regular moving class. I have tried a couple of things, but all felt wrong somehow. I worked through interfaces for the unidimensional moving parts, but there is a default underlying behavior that should extend to all objects moving in that direction, and thus it feels wrong to write these over and over again. I tried the reverse and have for example the horizontal class extend the MovingObject class, but with all its vertical components set to 0, which somehow felt even worse.

I know this might not seem like a very important detail, but it has been driving me crazy for some reason. Mostly because I come from C++.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> I would love to have an abstract class "HorizontalMovingObject" and
>   "VerticalMovingObject", and have an abstract class "MovingObject"
>   which extends both these classes.

The workaround for that is interface.
`MovingObject` should implement both `HorizontalMovingObject` and `VerticalMovingObject`

> I currently have these abstract classes, but find myself constantly
>   copying code from the unidimensional moving classes to the regular
>   moving class. I have tried a couple of things, but all felt wrong
>   somehow.

Java 8 introduces default methods that allow to define default implementations for interfaces.
Note that if a class implements both `HorizontalMovingObject` and `VerticalMovingObject` , which both have a same default method, you should override it to make the class compile : default interfaces allow to mix inherited behaviors from distinct interfaces while no ambiguity is present about which method is inherited. When it is not the case, a compilation error occurs.

An alternative to Java 8 interfaces default method to achieve this requirement is using the decorator pattern : define each part of behavior that you want to reuse in a specific decorator class, chain the decorators designed to work together and and add these to the decorated class that need these specific behavior.
This approach favors composition over inheritance and requires more boiler plate code but is more flexible.

Comment: Didn't know about the default methods, that's exactly what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that can be done for multiple inheritance is using default methods of interfaces.

I personally don't think it's a good idea, this is not what default methods are there for, but technically it's a loop-hole you can expliot

A better solution for me can be to have some `MovingObjectAbs` class that will hold the shared direction-agnostic logic that both horizontal and vertical classes will extend, or to have some utility classes that will have shared logic.